Switch Between Windows of the Same Application Across Multiple Monitors on Mac
I have an external monitor connected to my MacBook as an extended display. On desktop 1 (the MacBook's screen), I have an instance of Firefox open in workspace 1. On desktop 2 (the external monitor), I have another instance of Firefox open in a different workspace. Both instances are currently in full-screen mode.
When I focus on desktop 1 and press Cmd+Tab to switch to Mail, it works as expected. However, when I try to switch back to Firefox on the same display using the same shortcut, nothing happens. It seems that macOS recognizes Firefox as already open but doesn't bring me back to the workspace I just switched from.
How can I achieve this?

This question is similar to: Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is different for the following reason: When there is only one monitor, you can toggle between windows as long as they are not full screen. But with multiple monitors, i don;t see how to achieve this even when the applications aren't in full screen

What do you mean with instance? Is FF running once, with two windows open, or did you duplicate the FF binary and each is running with one window open?

@nohillside Yes, FF running once, with two windows open. Same binary. Sorry for the confusion.
